# Making an entire <div> become a link?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there a way to make the entire area of a `<div>` be a proper link?

Right now I'm doing this with javascript using the `onclick` but this is not good since if I middle click it (on firefox) it doesn't open at all

Comment: Middle click? If I middle click on a link in Firefox, some auto-scroll function will trigger. I think that is the normal behaviour.

Comment: I do not know much JavaScript, but can you use onmouseup instead of onclick?

Comment: @Pekka: That depends on your mouse /software/. Many mice have a programmable middle click behaviour.

Comment: JavaScript probably shouldn't be used for something as important as a link; if it's disabled in the visitor's browser, they'll never get to your content.

Comment: @Pekka assuming drivers don't consume the event, most modern browsers open the link in a new tab if you middle-click

Comment: @Matt oh, you're right, I just noticed (the auto scroll thingy appears when clicking and moving the mouse.) And obviously `onclick` is too narrow then. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 12):

Your best choice would probably be to turn a link into a block element.

CSS:
`#mylink { display: block; }`

HTML:
`<a href="#" id="mylink">Some Content</a>`

Comment: because divs are just undifferentiated blocks?

Comment: With this, can I still have `<img>`, `<h1>` etc inside the link block?

Comment: Yes you will.  Anything that can go inside a normal link can go inside one with a block style.

Comment: Actually, no. When I put a `<h1>` inside an `<a>` the page fails validation.

Comment: "Anything that can go inside a normal link can go inside one with a block style."

That still stands. `<a>` tags should not contain block elements.

Answer (score 5):

What do you have inside the DIV? If it's just text and other inline elements, you can just do:

```
<div><a href="#" style="display: block;">....</a></div>
```